# How can you have boolean -datatype in VP-uml?

Tags: database, uml, boolean, erd

**My ERD is**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-8.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-8.png)

I use at the moment `integer(2)` to signal that the datatype is boolean because the program does not allow me to type boolean to the datatype -field.

**How can you have boolean as a datatype in the program VP-uml?**

[edit]

The problem still persists.

I see the following in my VP-uml:

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/vp-uml-datatype-bug-boolean.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/vp-uml-datatype-bug-boolean.png)

Comment: This question is belong to Stack over flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/highlight/highlightcustomizabledatatypes.jsp

Comment: The problem is now solved. Boolean is in my model `bool`. Thank you for your answer!